# sbt how to pass command line parameters when more than one executable

Tags: command-line, sbt

My project has a few executables. How may we run one of them **with supplied command line arguments**  ?  After attempting to include the args from **sbt run** they are ignored and instead the menu of available main's are listed:

```
C:\apps\simpleakka>sbt run "com.mycompany.sparkpoc.hbase.HBasePop spark://localhost:7088 localhost:2181 1000 100"
[info] Loading project definition from C:\apps\simpleakka\project
[info] Set current project to simpleakka (in build file:/C:/apps/simpleakka/)

Multiple main classes detected, select one to run:

 [1] com.mycompany.sparkpoc.LCS
 [2] com.mycompany.sparkpoc.rdd.HBaseMR
 [3] org.apache.spark.examples.HwHBaseTest
 [4] com.mycompany.sparkpoc.rdd.HBaseMROld
 [5] com.mycompany.sparkpoc.HBaseTest
 [6] com.mycompany.sparkpoc.SocketServer
 [7] com.mycompany.sparkpoc.hbase.HBasePop
```

But by selecting one of the seven options, the command line args are lost:

```
Enter number:

Invalid number: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Jun 25, 2014 6:12:07 PM
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass straight from the command line, just by enclosing between quotes, like this:

```
$ sbt "runMain com.mycompany.sparkpoc.hbase.HBasePop spark://localhost:7088 localhost:2181 1000 100"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to run a specific main class, you can use `runMain`, and to pass command line arguments you have to specify them after the main class name.

```
> help runMain
Runs the main class selected by the first argument, passing the remaining arguments to the main method.
```

For example

```
> runMain sample.hello.Main firstArg secondArg thirdArg
```

Comment: This is still valid but the next answer - "straight from the command line" is an even more direct one, thus I switched the acceptance. Hope you don't mind ;)

Answer (score 4):

The closest workaround is a bit hokey but still acceptable:

```
sbt  (go into the console, not sure the following were possible directly from command line)
```

Now:

```
run <command args>
```

Then the list of 7 main's comes up.

Type the selection number (7 in my case)

Somehow the sbt "remembers" the command line options and runs it now.